# Difference between Soc (system on chip) and SBC (single board computer)

Tags: embedded, hardware

Can anyone please explain the major differences between a Soc and SBC?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SBC is a PCB, SoC a chip.

SBC may contain a SoC (a chip) in addition to other components and connectors to build a stand-alone system. SoC in itself is rarely standalone but needs at least a few extra components and at least some connectors for power and interfacing.

A bit like car(SBC) and engine(SoC). A standalone engine is not functional but needs to be placed in a car.

Comment: in any case +1 but... then the ESP8266 is a chip only? and the microcontroller inside it, the Cadence Tensilica LX106, is not a chip? so a microcontroller is not a chip? NodeMCU is then a SBC (a SoC with a dev board)? And the Arduino is an SBC? Does the Arduino then contain an SoC as you said?

Answer (score 6):

SOC = System on a Chip

SBC = Single Board Computer

A SOC has multiple functional units on one piece of silicon.  Often multiple processors and peripherals.

A SBC is a complete PC on a single PCB.  CPU, RAM, non-volatile memory(HDD or flash)...

Comment: +1 but would the Raspberry Pi classify as a SBC? or not because it doesn't come with flash/HDD on the same board? how about the ESP8266? The ESP8266 is definitely less of a computer than a RPi, but it does come with its own flash, and it even has wifi built-in.

Comment: @Erik Allik - yes the RPi would be a SBC and the Broadcom BCM2835 is the SoC on that board.

Answer (score 2):

System on Chip (SoC) and [Single Board Computer](https://www.toradex.com/products/customized-single-board-computer) (SBC) are totally different to each other. Usually SOC is an important constituent of the SBC. 
System-on-a-chip (SoC) is an Integrated Circuit which houses all the critical elements of the electronic system on a single microchip. A SoC can usually have the on-chip memory, microprocessor, peripheral interfaces, , I/O logic control, etc. that are usually found inside a computer system. It is widely used across the embedded industry due to their small-form-factor, computational excellence and low power consumption. 
SBCs are off-the-shelf products that can be used to develop end-products or applications for a variety of industries. SBCs come along with integrated software and hardware, which includes System on Chips, memory, power requirements, real world multimedia and connectivity interfaces such as USB, UART, CAN, HDMI, Ethernet, SDIO, MMC, Analog Audio, display etc.